# sum ongamma variate and probability

Tags: probability

The daily consumption of milk in a city, in excess of 20,000 L is approximately 
 distributed as a Gamma variate with the parameters α=2 and 
10,000
1
λ = .The city 
 has a daily stock of 30,000 litres. What is the probability that the stock is insufficient 
 on a particular day?